# Conectar a varias base de datos mysql y c#

Tags: mysql, c#, conexión

Hola estoy buscando como crear una clase conexión en c# pero esta se pueda conectar a varias base de datos en diferentes servidores mysql, lo siguiente es mi clase pero solo a una base de datos:

```
public abstract class DConexion
{
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string DB { get; set; }
    public string Port { get; set; }

    private readonly string conexionstring;

    public DConexion()
    {
        this.Server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["host"];
        this.Port = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"];
        this.DB = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["database"];
        this.User = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["user"];
        this.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pass"];

        conexionstring = "server=" + Server + ";port=" + Port + ";database=" + DB + ";uid=" + User + ";pwd=" + Password + ";";
    }

    protected MySqlConnection GetConexion()
    {
        return new MySqlConnection(conexionstring);
    }          
}
```

La idea que se me ocurre es crear un método, el cual pida un valor para opción y con este saber si se conecta a una u otra base de datos.
En el archivo de configuración tengo otro grupo de parámetros los cuales puedo modificar para pasar los valores y saber a que base de datos conectar.

Comment: Aplica tu idea que por ahi va la cosa

Comment: Hola Alex, resolviste tu problema?

Comment: Si, lo hice de una manera como lo imaginaba, no se si este del todo correcto, pero funciona....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta forma me funciono, por si a alguien le sirve, o puede mejorarlo...

```
public MySqlConnection CreaConexion(int popcion){
    Conexion = popcion;
    if (Conexion == 1) //Conexion local
    {
        this.Server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["host"];
        this.User = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["user"];
        this.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pass"];
        this.DataBase = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["database"];
        this.Port = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"];

        conexionstring = "server=" + Server + ";port=" + Port + ";database=" + DataBase + ";uid=" + User + ";pwd=" + Password + ";";
    }
    else // Conexion externa
    {
        this.Server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["hostext"];
        this.Port = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["portext"];
        this.DataBase = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["databaseext"];
        this.User = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userext"];
        this.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["passext"];

        conexionstring = "server=" + Server + ";port=" + Port + ";database=" + DataBase + ";uid=" + User + ";pwd=" + Password + ";";
    }

    return new MySqlConnection(conexionstring);}
```